# How do I register that the progress bar has completed and run another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Javascript function. When i click a button, the button disappears and reveals a progress bar. How can I register that the time is up and run another function?

```
$('#go').click(function() {
  console.log("moveProgressBar");

  $('.progress-wrap').removeClass('hidden');

  var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
  var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
  var animationLength = 1000;

  $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
    left: progressTotal
    }, animationLength);
  $('#go').addClass('hidden');

});
```

http://codepen.io/TrueVineCS/pen/vuyxC

Comment: animate method accepts a complete callback, check the DOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.animate` callback:

```
$('#go').click(function() {
  console.log("moveProgressBar");

  $('.progress-wrap').removeClass('hidden');

  var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
  var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
  var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
  var animationLength = 1000;

  $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
       left: progressTotal
    }, 
    animationLength, 
    function(){
       // do on animation is complete
       $('#go').addClass('hidden');
  });

});
```

[jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/), [your example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKbwq)